# How does AIDL work?

Tags: java, android-service, aidl

I am trying to implement AIDL and I just do not understand how it *works*. By this I mean what is the progression of calls to methods?

I dont understand how to get an object from the service to my activity through AIDL. 
I have been using [google docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html) for guidance but I am confused.Thanks

UPDATE:

In Service Connection I have these lines where mCallback is a IRemoteServiceCallback.

```
 public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            mRemoteInterface = IRemoteInterface.Stub.asInterface(service);
            Log.v(TAG, "Interface bound.");
            try{
                mRemoteInterface.registerCallback(mCallback);
            }catch(RemoteException e){

            }
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Remote Service Connected",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Here is registerCallback, where mCallbacks is a

```
final RemoteCallbackList <IRemoteServiceCallback> mCallbacks

    = new RemoteCallbackList <IRemoteServiceCallback> ();
```

.....

```
public void registerCallback(IRemoteServiceCallback callback)
                throws RemoteException {
            if(callback != null){
                mCallbacks.register(callback);
            }

        }
```

The only method that IRemoteServiceCallback(mCallback) has is:

```
public void valueChanged(int value) {
        mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(BUMP_MSG, value, 0));
    }
```

I also have a Handler but I am not quite sure what to do with that:

```
 private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case BUMP_MSG:
                Log.d(TAG, "Received from service: " + msg.arg1);
                break;
            default:
                super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    }

};
```

***UPDATE 2:***

AIDL Steps -from what I understand-.

1. I call bindService(service,connection,flags) from MainActivity
2. onServiceConnected is automatically called after I call bindService and a connection is established. Inside there, I get the IBinder and then call registerCallback which puts a IRemoteServiceCallback[**WHERE DOES THIS CALLBACK COME FROM??**] into RemoteCallbackList for later access

Now, I noticed that there are TWO mHandlers, one in the service and one in the activity. [**WHEN ARE THESE CALLED and WHAT IS THE DIFFERENCE BETWEEN THEM IN TERMS OF USAGE**]

Now, RemoteCallbackList has the callbacks that I need and I can see that in the mHandler of the activity class I am able to finally get the objects that I want.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Cross-application services in Android are based on Binder, a kernel-level IPC system (this is where the `IBinder` class name comes from). When you bind to a remote service (that is, one outside of your application), it can return an object to you. However, since you don't know what the actual type is (methods, fields, etc), you can't cast it to a usable type.

This is where AIDL comes in - it is a language-agnostic way of specifying *interfaces* - collections of methods and their parameters (it also looks deceptively like Java - it's not). If both the client and the server use the same .aidl file, you can bind to the object via the generated Java interfaces - `IRemoteService.Stub.asInterface(obj)`. On the service side you just have to implement that same interface in *some* language (some of the services in the framework are in C++) and the IPC mechanism will take care of the rest.

That said, you don't need to use AIDL unless you export your service and want external applications to be able to use it. If not, just implement IBinder in your application and cast the object received in `onServiceConnected` directly, since you know its type.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am doing AIDL because we might implement something down the line where this functionality is needed, but it isnt currently, is this okay?(As in will it still work if what I'm doing is all within one application). Also, could you explain what registerCallback and register do? If you could check the updated question and see the methods I am talking about that would be great.

Comment: I am still confused about the USE of this service. Where am I using the methods that I have in my IRemoteInterface? (I have them defined in my service but where do I use them?). How do I send my objects along?

Comment: Well, those are just methods on the RemoteService's IBinder in the example. You can find the implementation here - https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/RemoteService.java

In essence, they are just methods in the IBinder object that the service returns. You don't *have* to then forward the actual call to a Handler but remote methods are called from a variety of threads and that's probably the easiest way to make them thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It was very helpful. In my service, I will get a "Vehicle" ( a class that I made parcelable ) from a server. How do I send this vehicle back to the Main(the activity that is bound to the service)?

Comment: You can use the pattern in the sample - register a callback and later on send the Vehicle to all registered callbacks.

Comment: Thanks, I need to just stare at this all for a bit longer. I may post a followup question if you're still available. Thanks again

Comment: Hello again, @Delyan. I have posted what I believe is going on but I still can't figure out a couple things out. If you could clarify these for me I think I will know everything I need to know to use AIDL.

Comment: `IRemoteServiceCallback` is just another aidl file that's shared between the service and the client - you can find the [code here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/IRemoteServiceCallback.aidl). Essentially, it's just another type that both service and the client must be able to resolve unambiguously. 

As for the Handlers, the comment above the `mHandler.sendMessage` line in `valueChanged` explains it - remote methods are called on many threads and you need to make them thread-safe. Both sides have to do it.

Comment: Sorry I may have been unclear. In OnServiceConnected, it says mService.registerCallback(mCallback);. If mCallback is what is going into the callback list, then is mCallback what contains my "Vehicle" or no?

Comment: The callback is what is normally called a Listener in the framework. In your case, you might call it `VehicleListener` and it should probably have a method `onVehicleAdded(Vehicle vehicle)`. Then, you register it with the service. The service does its thing, then iterates over all the listeners and calls onVehicleAdded with your Parcelable Vehicle on each one. This is really no different from a `DataSetObservable` or a runtime `BroadcastReceiver`. The general idea is that the service and the client look like local objects. AIDL is just the type glue for that.

Comment: Could you please take a look at this problem that I am having? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17955094/aidl-interface-cant-find-import-for-parcelable-class